# can't create ssl session in web.py - Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, web.py

I'm trying to make my server use a https/ssl connection. I have the certificate and the key.
I've tried using the example in http://webpy.org/cookbook/ssl but it still uses http and not https. My web.py version is up-to-date (0.38), but I've tried to use the old implementation presented in the site aswell, which resulted in the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/path/server.py", line 7, in <module>
from web.wsgiserver.ssl_builtin import BuiltinSSLAdapter
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/web/wsgiserver/ssl_builtin.py", line 14, in <module>
from cherrypy import wsgiserver
ImportError: cannot import name wsgiserver
```

In the line:

```
from web.wsgiserver.ssl_builtin import BuiltinSSLAdapter
```

Any solution? (I guess not for the error since it resulted from a use that suitable for older releases of web.py, but for the first implementation).

Thanks

EDIT:
The code I'm running:

```
import sys
import web
from web.wsgiserver import CherryPyWSGIServer

from utils.tools import Tools

from pages.index import index
from pages.search import search
from pages.update_location import update_location
from pages.add_sn_tracking import add_sn_tracking
from pages.edit_sn_tracking import edit_sn_tracking
from pages.add_sheet_tracking import add_sheet_tracking
from pages.edit_sheet_tracking import edit_sheet_tracking


class WebServer:
    def __init__(self):
        CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_certificate = r"/Volumes/wlutils/Users/TesterUs/snserver/server.crt"
        CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_private_key = r"/Volumes/wlutils/Users/TesterUs/snserver/server.key"

        self.urls = (
            '/', 'index',
            '/search', 'search',
            '/update_location', 'update_location',
            '/add_sn_tracking', 'add_sn_tracking',
            '/edit_sn_tracking', 'edit_sn_tracking',
            '/add_sheet_tracking', 'add_sheet_tracking',
            '/edit_sheet_tracking', 'edit_sheet_tracking',
        )
        # web.config.debug = False
        self.app = web.application(self.urls, globals())
        self.app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     w = WebServer()
```

Comment: Just checking -- you're not fronting web.py using either nginx or apache, right?

Comment: Thats right, only web.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set up web.py for SSL, just set the internal CherryPyWSGIServer:

```
from web.wsgiserver import CherryPyWSGIServer
CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_certificate = "/file/my.crt"
CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_private_key = "/file/my.key"
```

Do this prior to your call to `app = web.application(urls, globals())`. If that's not working for you, let's explore that, rather than the pre-v.0.38 solution you're attempting, known to not work for current `web.py`.

Followup: it appears that an older version of `web.py` was being used. Once that was updated to 0.38+ the example worked.

Comment: That's what I tried at first, it just creates a regular http session anyway

Comment: Show sample code, please. The documented solution works, so we need more from you to understand what is different.

Comment: Your updated code appears to work fine (cut and paste). You should get on startup, `https://0.0.0.0:8080/`, the address the server is listening on. If you're getting something different, perhaps check the version of web.py you're using.

Comment: You're right! For some reason I had the updated version of web.py in /usr/local/libs and old version in /Libraries from where took the web.py. When I've updated the web.py in Libraries everything's working. Thank you.

Comment: Great! (because I was out of answers.)